# crypto kernel module not avialable on linux 3.18.11 on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: linux, debian, encryption, kernel, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to use dm-crypt on my Raspberry Pi 2 with Raspbian (debian) to open a trueCrypt volume, but i get

```
Required kernel crypto interface not available.
Ensure you have algif_skcipher kernel module loaded.
```

My research has yielded that algif_skcipher should be available since `2.6.38`, but my kernel version is `3.18.11-v7+` (according to `uname`). Why isn't the module available and, more importantly how can I fix this?